# Does react useEffect render changes or resets, state values to zero?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

After every render does, useEffect() hook resets all the useState() values states?

Comment: No, it wouldn't be very useful if the state was not maintained between renders

Comment: That's the purpose of states refs and everything to keep things between rerenders

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

State stays the same between renders. It does not change when using useEffect().